# div to dissapear on load and appear on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written the css, js and html for this simple application to appear on scroll and it still won't run in html? Maybe it's the way I'm connecting it in my html but that seems fine I have searhed many sites to confirm it's right... I don't know where I'm going wrong.

**CSS:**

```
.aboutfilmandcrew {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}
#filminfo{
    padding:1em;
    border:.1em solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    margin: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;    
}
#crew{
    padding:1em;
    border:.1em solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    margin: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div id="filminfo"> Neuromancer, a novel written by William Gibson in 1984, takes place in the near future in a cyberpunk setting. Cyberpunk is a genre that focuses on future societies where technology has advanced, but crime and corruption have as well. Common features include globe-spanning mega-corporations, cybernetically enhanced mercenaries, and the importance of technology as a tool for crime. The story follows the experiences of Case, an out-of-work hacker who is contacted by a mysterious new employer called Armitage. Along with Molly, a mercenary cyborg, and a thief/illusionist named Peter Riviera, Case participates in a series of data thefts for their employer. Based on the novel, and helmed by master director Ridley Scott, NEUROMANCER features a star studded cast that includes Ryan Gosling, Lucy Liu, Hayden Christensen and Benedict Cumberbatch.
        <br/>
        <h4> GENRES </h4> <p>Sci fi/Adventure </p>
    </div>
    <!---aboutfilm-->
    <div id="crew">
        <p>Director Ridley Scott </p>
        <p> Screenplay by Drew Goddard </p>
        <p> Based on the Novel By William Gibson </p>
        <p> Producers Simon Kinberg, Ridley Scott, Michael Schaefer, Aditya Sood, Mark Huffam </p>
        <p> Actors Ryan Gosling, Lucy Liu, Hayden Christensen and Benedict Cumberbatch </p>
    </div>
</div>
<!---crew-->
<!---aboutfilmandcrew-->
```

**JS:**

```
  $(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (y > 200) {
    $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeIn();
  } else {
  console.log("<");
    $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeOut();
  }
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $(".aboutfilmandcrew").hide();
  });
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 200) {
        $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```css
.aboutfilmandcrew {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}

#filminfo {
    padding: 1em;
    border: .1em solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    margin: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

#crew {
    padding: 1em;
    border: .1em solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    margin: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
}

body {
    height: 1600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="aboutfilmandcrew">
        <div id="filminfo"> Neuromancer, a novel written by William Gibson in 1984, takes place in the near future in a cyberpunk setting. Cyberpunk is a genre that focuses on future societies where technology has advanced, but crime and corruption have as well. Common features include globe-spanning mega-corporations, cybernetically enhanced mercenaries, and the importance of technology as a tool for crime. The story follows the experiences of Case, an out-of-work hacker who is contacted by a mysterious new employer called Armitage. Along with Molly, a mercenary cyborg, and a thief/illusionist named Peter Riviera, Case participates in a series of data thefts for their employer. Based on the novel, and helmed by master director Ridley Scott, NEUROMANCER features a star studded cast that includes Ryan Gosling, Lucy Liu, Hayden Christensen and Benedict Cumberbatch.
            <br/>
            <h4> GENRES </h4>
            <p> Sci fi/Adventure </p>
        </div>
        <!---aboutfilm-->
        <div id="crew">
            <p>Director Ridley Scott </p>
            <p> Screenplay by Drew Goddard </p>
            <p> Based on the Novel By William Gibson </p>
            <p> Producers Simon Kinberg, Ridley Scott, Michael Schaefer, Aditya Sood, Mark Huffam </p>
            <p> Actors Ryan Gosling, Lucy Liu, Hayden Christensen and Benedict Cumberbatch </p>
        </div>
        <!---crew-->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

There is a `</p>` after `Sci fi/Adventure` that you've never opened. Just add the starting `<p>` so you can easily fix this error.

EDIT: If you want to do what you've commented you have to set a specific size to the body in CSS.

```
body{
    height:1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, your code is working as you needed.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 200) {
        $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```css
.aboutfilmandcrew {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
#filminfo {
    padding: 1em;
    border: .1em solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    margin: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;    
}
#crew {
    padding: 1em;
    border: .1em solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
    margin: 2em;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aboutfilmandcrew">
  <p id="filminfo"> 
    Neuromancer, a novel written by William Gibson in 1984, takes place in the near future in a cyberpunk setting. Cyberpunk is a genre that focuses on future societies where technology has advanced, but crime and corruption have as well. Common features include globe-spanning mega-corporations, cybernetically enhanced mercenaries, and the importance of technology as a tool for crime.
    The story follows the experiences of Case, an out-of-work hacker who is contacted by a mysterious new employer called Armitage. Along with Molly, a mercenary cyborg, and a thief/illusionist named Peter Riviera, Case participates in a series of data thefts for their employer.  Based on the novel, and helmed by master director Ridley Scott, NEUROMANCER features a star studded cast that includes Ryan Gosling, Lucy Liu, Hayden Christensen and Benedict Cumberbatch.
    <h4>GENRES</h4>
    Sci fi/Adventure
  </p>
</div>

<div id="crew">
    <p>Director Ridley Scott </p>
    <p> Screenplay by Drew Goddard </p>
    <p> Based on the Novel By William Gibson </p>
    <p> Producers Simon Kinberg, Ridley Scott, Michael Schaefer, Aditya Sood, Mark Huffam </p>
    <p> Actors Ryan Gosling, Lucy Liu, Hayden Christensen and Benedict Cumberbatch </p>
</div>
```

Comment: no i want the text and divs to dissapear on load and then appear when i scroll down ?